# Перспективы С++ сегодня ?

Tags: c#, java, c++

Привет коллеги ! Заканчиваю 5-тый курс своего универа, 3 года мы учили только Ассемблер, Си и последний год С++. У нас на кафедре очень смутно понимают что такое Java, C# а так же проектирование ПО и все те вещи которые нужны разработчику. Сам я посмотрел на рынок и очень удивился что С++ вакансий намного меньше чем Java, C#, а для джунов вакансий вообще нет, то есть на нашем рынке он скоро будет динозавром, знакомые мне рекомендуют спрыгивать на что-то популярное типа Java,C#,php,python ! C++ конечно очень сложный язык но вроде время потратил на него дофига итп... А как вы видите перспективы "плюсов" сегодня ?

Comment: @Alexey_Gmail, отвечу вам как пхпшник-самоучка.
Я вам дико завидую, потому что плюсы и просто си - это, как минимум, боевая школа кодинга.  
Если вы посмотрите сишарп или яву, то увидите там куда более простой синтаксис и многие срезанные углы. Если вы действительно разбираетесь в плюсах, то войти в яву или шарп будет довольно просто, как и в любой другой мейнстримовый язык.  
Рынок действительно раздут не в ту сторону, и, возможно, вы будете писать на другом языке, но ваши знания вряд ли пропадут. Как минимум это понимание происходящего внутри PHP/Python и возможность проанализировать сорцы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вакансий для С++-программистов действительно существенно меньше, нежели для прочих мэйнстрим-языков. Тому есть много причин, и ожидать, что в ближайшее (да и в какое-либо вообще) время это изменится, я бы не стал. Ситуация, когда "у нас на кафедре очень смутно понимают что такое Java, C# а так же проектирование ПО" - это, к сожалению, весьма обычное дело для нашего высшего образования.

Вам еще в какой-то степени повезло изучать именно С++ - многие другие студенты все пять лет ковыряются в какой-нибудь древней версии Delphi. В целом все не так печально. Я не знаю вашей ситуации (где именно вы живете, где хотите работать и каков ваш уровень), но в целом в данный момент вы еще не целиком сформировавшийся программист, а потому можете вполне безболезненно перейти на другой язык. Это займет не столь много времени, как может казаться. Вне зависимости от того, с каким языком вы в итоге свяжете свою работу, я вас уверяю, непосредственно на работе вам предстоит узнать огромную кучу всего нового, чему в институтах по тем или иным причинам не учат. А потому, пока вы еще не жестко привязали себя к тем или иным технологиям, зоопарку фреймворков, библиотек, инструментов, вы можете легко пересесть на любой другой язык. В целом любой другой популярный ныне язык существенно легче (а местами и куда удобнее), чем С++, к тому же многие из них хотя бы косвенно, но похожи на С++,  поэтому если вы осилили С++, то проблем с  Java, C# или PHP быть не должно. В общем и целом я не призываю вас отказываться от С++, однако советовал бы вам присмотреться также к какому-либо еще языку. Лишним это точно не будет

Answer (score 2):

**схема "на завод к мастеру"**

Обходите конторы одну за одной и берёте тестовые задания на дом. Выполняете, читаете, изучаете. Потом идёте туда, куда возьмут. Открывайте только свои карты сразу, говорите что именно не знаете, и что готовы учится.

Вообще не важен ни язык, ни предметная область. Нужен хороший коллектив который вас всему научит.

Answer (score 1):

Перспективы есть, пусть и не такие широкие, как раньше.
А то, что нет вакансий для джунов - это естественно, ибо порог вхождения выше, чем в managed языках. Но, как говорится, нет ничего невозможного, пробившихся рублем не обижают.

Answer (score 1):

Как знакома ситуация ...... лично я в свое время сделал выбор в сторону java в частности  android ─ уж больно там модель ооп красивая, хотя и на c# кодить приходилось  ))  пока есть время определяейтсь, для меня серьезным аргументом в сторону android стала возможность найти удаленную работу ─ все же java и  c# чаще требуется в офис, а у меня географически софтверных фирм нет (